# Redirect after login to backbone route with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, backbone.js

I am attempting to provide users with a common functionality, redirecting them after login to the originally requested url that is behind a secure path.  Example, user clicks link in email triggered via notification in the system, attempts to go to:
https://mysite.com/secure/notifications/1
User is not logged in so kicked back to
https://mysite.com/login
After login they should be brought not to their home page, but to the originally requested url.

I am familar with the technique to store the attempted URL in session before redirecting to login page.  The issue is if the URL contains a backbone router after the core URL, ie
https://mysite.com/secure/notifications/1#details

The #details part of the URL is not sent to server it seems, as this is typically for inner page jumping.  I am wondering how are web developers dealing with this as JS MVC frameworks like backbone, angular, and other are emerging?  Some trick?  Any way to actually have the # pass to server in http specification?

Any ideas are appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution to this problem, if you don't need to support this behaviour for older browsers, is to enable pushState in your backbone router so you don't use `#` for routes:

`Backbone.history.state({pushState: true});`

**Edit:**

The other potential solution, though it is a bit messy, is to do some URL tomfoolery to figure out what should be after the hash and then navigate to that route.

For example, let's say that you want to navigate to:

`http://webapp.com/abc/#page1` where 'page1' is the fragment which makes up the Backbone route.

If you instead send the user to `http://webapp.com/abc/page1`. You can detect whether the browser has pushState. If not, you can replace everything after the 'root' with the hash. Here is some example code which might get you on the right track to supporting both sets of browsers:

```js
    var _defaults = {
      pushState: Modernizr.history,
      silent: true,
      root: '/'
    };

    var start = function(options) {
      // Start the routing either with pushstate or without
      options = _.extend(_.clone(this._defaults), options);
      Backbone.history.start(options);
      if (options.pushState) {
        Backbone.history.loadUrl(Backbone.history.getFragment());
        return;
      }
      this.degradeToNonHistoryURL();
    };

    /**
     * For fragment URLs, we check if the actual request is for the root i.e '/',
     * If it is, we can continue and Backbone will do the magic
     * If it isn't we redirect to the root with the route as a fragment
     * foo.com/bar/1 -> foo.com/#bar/1
     */
    degradeToNonHistoryURL = function() {
        var pathName = window.location.pathname;

        // If the root is '/', length is one. If the root is 'foo', length is 5 (/foo/)
        var rootLength = _getRoot().length;
        var isRootRequest = pathName.length === rootLength;
        if (!isRootRequest) {
          var route = pathName.substr(rootLength);
          window.location.href = _getRoot() + '#' + route + window.location.search;
          return;
        }
        Backbone.history.loadUrl(Backbone.history.getFragment());
      },

      /**
       * Get the effective root of the app. Normally it's '/', but if set to 'foo', we want
       * to return '/foo/' so we can more easily determine if this is a root request or not.
       * @returns {String} The effective root
       */
      _getRoot = function() {
        if (Backbone.history.options.root === '/') {
          return '/';
        }
        return '/' + Backbone.history.options.root + '/';
      },
```

The trick here is making the pushState URL your canonical URLs and always sending users to those ones. Once browser adoption increases, it should theoretically be easy to cut all of this crap out without having to update all of your links.

Comment: if you are giving a full URL path to someone not logged in, how does that work?  Is part of the URL determine which BB view you go to based on url parameters?

Comment: Here are some articles explaining why hash and hashbang tags are not ideal.  http://danwebb.net/2011/5/28/it-is-about-the-hashbangs, http://artsy.github.io/blog/2012/06/25/replacing-hashbang-routes-with-pushstate/.

Comment: Here is an article about understanding pushstate, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: Will I gave you +1 however this requires a large change and for existing apps I think not feasible without great effort.  I was hoping for another solution, guess not.

Comment: Hey bmj88, I added some more detail of code that I wrote a while ago to handle this case. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

After some research it seems there are only two solutions

1. As recommended by Will, use pushState and only support HTML5 browsers, but this is a massive change for existing apps using hash or hashbang javascript navigation.
2. Workarounds on server side, the main option here is around providing redirect endpoints to get users where then need to go.  Example
   /myapp/redirector?pathroot=notifications&hashroot=details&hashparam1=2
   this would then build up a url on server side
   /myapp/notifications/1#details/2

So in #2 the server cannot receive http requests with hashtags, however it can send them.  The browser will receive this full path including hash nav part, and do its normal javascript MVC routing thing.